# DateTimePicker Alignment in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, alignment, datetimepicker

My problem is following: I need to align text inside DateTimePicker component to center. This component however doesn't have Alignment property. This component comes from TCommonCalendar, which also doesn't have this property. Can anybody think of possible solution?

Thank you,
Tofig Hasanov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many alternatives to TDateTimePicker out there, for a reason: They can the stuff that TDateTimePicker cannot.

Comment: I have tried WollToWoll, Jedi, Raize & DevExpress. From these list, only DevExpress is capable of what you ask (for the mere fact it doesn't use the standard windows control).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible.

Behind the scenes, when you create a TDateTimePicker, a window common control *SysDateTimePick32* get's created. It looks like it does not allow it's Style to be changed from ES_LEFT to ES_CENTER (or ES_RIGHT for that matter).

I hope to be proven wrong.